# Escuchar cambios en Firebase Database con Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Tengo en Firebase Database unos datos así:

```
- order
    -catched : false
    -completed : false
- user
    -name : ejemplo
```

Quisiera que al pasar a un Activity, este se quede escuchando de manera **persistente** si ocurre un cambio en "catched", en este caso si llega a cambiar a "true"; para así poder ejecutar otra acción cuando ocurra dicho evento. ¿Como podría hacer esto?

Gracias y quedo atento.

Comment: Firebase lo hace por si solo, siempre esta escuchando cuando lo implementas, se actualiza en tiempo real, solo pon un If donde obtienes los datos en tu aplicacion y si catched es true hara tal accion. Sin mas.

Comment: Como dice @EduardoRicardez, Firebase lo hace por si solo. Solo asegurate de que ese Activity esté activo y no estes removiendo los listeners en su ciclo de vida, por ejemplo: onStop(), onPause() en caso de que estés guardando la referencia de sus eventos. Si estás usando un Adapter, lo mejor sería actualizar su lista en el activity y notificarle. Si tienes una referencia a un Fragmento u otro activity, puedes crear un Callback o establecer un método público set y hacer una llamada con el valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Supongo que el proyecto en FB ya está creado y tu app en android con los agregados necesarios)

1) Referencia

```
DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mOrderRef = mRootRef.child("order");
```

2) Obtener el valor del child deseado

```
mOrderRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            boolean mCatched = dataSnapshot.child("catched").getValue(boolean.class); 

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

3) El valor ahora esta en mCatched y puedes utilizarla como sea necesario.